# How to request permission to write to removable sd card in Android 5.0 and above

Tags: android, uri, android-5.0-lollipop, file-permissions

A simple question. By default android doesn't allow 3rd party apps to write to removable sd card.

But in Android 5.0 I can request for permission to write to removable sdcard and write any file in that directory.

So how to do that? I need an output stream to write to the file.

Comment: Are you referring to [external storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/08/storage-situation-external-storage.html) or [removable storage](https://commonsware.com/blog/2014/04/09/storage-situation-removable-storage.html)?

Comment: @CommonsWare I was talking about removable storage. I have edited my post. I found many articles to request write permission in Android 6.0 (Marshmallow)  but I didn't find how to do that in Android 5.0 (Lollipop)

Comment: It does not help you very much knowing how to ask write permissions as micro SD card in Android 5 and above is non writable. Only the app specific directory on it can be written to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I can request for permission to write to external sdcard and write any file in that directory.

Not really.

On Android 4.4+, you can use `getExternalFilesDirs()`, `getExternalCacheDirs()`, and `getExternalMediaDirs()`. If those return 2+ items, the second and subsequent ones will be locations on removable storage.

On Android 5.0+, you can use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE`, to ask the user to grant you access to a document tree. That *could* be the root of removable storage... or anything else the user wants to use. This gives you a `Uri` back, which you can use with `DocumentFile` and the rest of the Storage Access Framework. It does *not* give you filesystem access (e.g., via `File`).

On Android 7.0+, you can use `StorageManager` and `StorageVolume` to ask for access to a removable storage volume. Once again, though, you get a `Uri` back to use with `DocumentFile`, `ContentResolver`, etc -- you do not get filesystem access.

Comment: How does es explorer do it ?